# Something that is the frequent cause of mistakes?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's imagine a hypothetical business: Mistake Corp. Mistake Corp makes a lot of mistakes, and as it turns out, the reason they make these mistakes is typically the same. 90% of the time Mistake Corp makes a mistake, it's because of misinformation. I suppose misinformation is the opposite of a linchpin for Mistake Corp.

I'd like to be able to use the word like so:
"Misinformation is the [anti-linchpin] of Mistake Corp"

What non-ambiguous word, other than "anti-linchpin", can I use to describe something that is a frequent cause for mistakes to those who aren't as English-savvy?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52683/discussion-on-question-by-drew-something-that-is-the-frequent-cause-of-mistakes).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say that misinformation is the [***pitfall***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pitfall) for Mistake Corp.

> A hidden or unsuspected danger or difficulty:
> *‘There are obvious pitfalls of such behavior, if it ever developed into a habit.’*

They indeed seem to fall in time and again; check the box for unsuspected...

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pitfall

Comment: I agree this is a good word but I'm not sure about the phrasing. Usually when you say "X is a pitfall of Y", Y refers to an activity which has that pitfall. You wouldn't normally place the person/group *making* the mistake in the Y position.

Comment: Like Ben, I'm not sure about the phrasing -- I'd personally choose "Misinformation is a pitfall _for_ Mistake Corp." But this is definitely a word that can be universally understood, and I like that it specifically implies shortcomings rather than a generic weakness.

Comment: @Ben Aaronson, Drew, made the edit :-)

Answer (score 29):

I would suggest ***[bane](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bane)***. The second definition from Merriam-Webster:

> 2. a source of harm or ruin

In context, you can say **"Misinformation is the bane of Mistake Corp."** The word is often used in play with [boon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boon), an antonym. For example, "The bane and boon of business."

You might also consider ***[curse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curse)***. The fifth definition in Merriam-Webster:

> 5. a cause of great harm or misfortune

In context: **"Misinformation is a constant curse for Mistake Corp."**

Comment: bane sounds better.

Comment: +1 for *bane*. *Curse*, not so much.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps **bugbear** would fit the context. According to [the Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bugbear), one of its meanings is:

> A difficult or persistent problem: *"One of the major bugbears of traditional AI is the difficulty of programming computers to recognize that different but similar objects are instances of the same type of thing"* (Jack Copeland).

The same page also quotes from the Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary:

> a persistent problem or source of annoyance.

In your case, misinformation would be the *bugbear* of Mistakes Corp.  The word does carry the sense of fear and dread, so the assumption would be that there is anxiety around misinformation, as it is a recognized source of persistent problems.

Comment: If I could squander my +1's for the next 100 questions I read, I would +1 them here.  I typed "Ctrl F bugbear" after reading the question.  If you need an actor for *threw a spanner in the works* it's *bugbear.*

Answer (score 11):

How about **stumbling block**?

In Merriam Webster's first definition, it is:

> an obstacle to progress

which a cause of continually repeated mistakes decidedly is.

Comment: This and bugbear are far more accurate answers than the current top answers (bane, pitfall, undoing).

Answer (score 9):

Note: this is not a figurative term like 'linchpin' . There are some other good choices in the comments and answers. Still, this is a possibility.

***undoing***

```
 "Misinformation is the [undoing] of Mistake Corp"
```

However, 'undoing' is a strong term and could imply Mistake Corp might be going out of business. (a undoing a linchpin could be fatal too though)

Instead, if you inserted 'frequent'

```
 "Misinformation is the [ *frequent undoing* ] of Mistake Corp"
```

It would be clear that while serious it logically couldn't be quite as severe if repeatable.

I think it could be easily understood by people relatively new to the language.

> ***undoing*** [uhn-doo-ing]
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/undoing)
>
> noun
>
> 1.
>   the reversing of what has been done; annulling.
>
> 2.
>   a bringing to destruction, ruin, or disaster.
>
> 3.
>   a cause of destruction or ruin.
>
> 4.
>   the act of unfastening or loosing.

Comment: 'Frequent undoing' sounds _very_ [contrived](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frequent+undoing%2C+their+undoing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrequent%20undoing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctheir%20undoing%3B%2Cc0). Undoing is rarely used in cases where disaster isn't meant to be implied.

Comment: "Misinformation has frequently been the undoing of Mistake Corp", you need the extra words in there to fix the rhythm.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not wholeheartedly into my own answer for the reasons both of you cite...

Comment: It brings to mind a Victorian heroine with her hand to her forehead, saying, "Alas! That villain has deceived me and stolen my honour! I am undone!" 

Answer (score 3):

**blind spot**

Misinformation is the blind spot of Mistake Corp.

> 2 :  an area in which one fails to exercise judgment or discrimination

"Blind Spot." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 23 Jan. 2017.

Answer (score 2):

When I was working as a Quality Manager and Analyst, we would run Histogram/Pareto analysis to identify "[**Critical Defects**](http://www.ge.com/sixsigma/glossary.html)". This is a type of analysis commonly used in Lean / Six Sigma, which is a management technique used to improve quality in processes by identifying and removing errors. It is commonly referred to as the 80/20 rule: 80% of total errors are caused by only 20% of the metrics.

A **[Root-cause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cause_analysis)**  is essentially some kind of factor that is the major reason for the failure of a process. Removal of the root cause should result in success of the process.

I suppose you could say that:

"Information collection is the most important ***critical defect*** in processes at Mistake Corp."

> "Misinformation is the ***root cause*** for this critical defect at Mistake Corp."

or words to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a stretch, perhaps, but **nemesis** or **bête noire** might also work in some contexts.

Comment: Sounds quite good to me, but a definition (and link/reference to where you got it from) for each suggestion would make this into a good answer worthy of an upvote.

Comment: I immediately thought of _bête noire_, but the [MW definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/b%C3%AAte%20noire) had a more specific meaning than I thought I remembered, particularly: "a person or thing strongly detested or avoided". I still like it as an answer; I was just surprised to see such a narrow definition.

Comment: @Spratty: The OED defines *bête noire* a little more broadly:  "A person or thing that is the bane of a person or his life; an insufferable person or thing; an object of aversion."

Answer (score 2):

**[Hindrance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hindrance)**

Misinformation is the [hindrance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hindrance) of Mistake Corp.

From Merriam-Webster:

> 2 : a person or thing that interferes with or slows the progress of someone or something :  impediment

Answer (score 1):

If the cause for mistakes is a person, I would suggest [liability](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liability):

> 3
>   :  one that acts as a disadvantage :  drawback

Answer (score -1):

You may simply call it a source of error. Otherwise I would agree with @Fredsbend that it is that company's bane.

Answer (score -9):

Cognitive dissonance

(Psychology) An uncomfortable mental state resulting from conflicting cognitions; usually resolved by changing some of the cognitions